# bash: command not found error

Tags: command-line, mac, terminal, python

I'm new to terminal, and am just following a beginners python course, I've saved an "example.py" file and im trying to open it but get this error?

[image]

also where it says "pc-79-59" that used to say the name of my MacBook as found in systems > sharing, but now it doesn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mq1998:

example.py is a file. If you want to edit a file you need a text editor like nano, vim, etc.

1. First, check if you have installed one of these. If you don't have installed a text editor, install with your package manager. For example, in ubuntu/debian you can install:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install packageName
```

2. To open a file, use the name of the text editor and the filename:

```
nano example.py
```

or

```
vim example.py
```

etc.

3. Finally, to execute your python program:

```
python example.py
```

And if the version you're using is python3, then:

```
python3 example.py
```

Check if you have installed the python interpreter.

Comment: thanks - I was executing it wrong - I had sublime text installed  !